# Break up NSData into byte packets to send to another device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsdata

1)How can I break up an NSData into chunks?

I want to iterate through the NSData and send each chunk via sendData GameKit.

2)The data that is being sent is an MP3. When the first chunk comes in, I want to convert it back to an MP3, start playing that file, then keep appending the remaining audio to it.  How do I?

Comment: Have you tried anything or checked the documentation? [`-(NSData *)subdataWithRange:(NSRange)range`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 4):

#### For the first the first part of your question...

You can break it up using the `getBytes:length:` and `getBytes:range:` instance methods.

Check the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

#### For the second part of your question...

Use `appendData`.  Of course this method for a `NSMutableData`.  Find the reference [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableData_Class/Reference/NSMutableData.html)

Comment: I'm not sure how to implement this. If I want 30kb segments, would I do something like :
int lastByteIndex;
NSRange myRange = NSRangeMake(0,30);
while (notEndofNSDataBytes)
{
  NSData *newData = [myData getBytes: myRange];
  myRange.location += 30;
  [sendData: newData];
}

I obviously don't know all the details of how to code this. Thoughts?